# Struct With Pointer Usage, SEGMENTATION FAULT

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I have a little problem with using struct array in C. It returns me segmentation fault

```
struct Yset{
char *unit;
char *name;
char *showValue;
char *fillColor;
char *yData;
};

struct Yset *svg_ysets;
int ySetCounter = 0;


svg_ysets[ySetCounter].unit = malloc(strlen((char*)attribute)+1);
strcpy(svg_ysets[ySetCounter].unit,(char*)attribute);
printf("%s\n", svg_ysets[ySetCounter].unit);
ySetCounter++;
```

What's wrong with this using? I dont know the number of Ysets so it must be dynamic. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
svg_ysets[ySetCounter].unit = malloc(strlen((char*)attribute)+1);
```

You are dereferencing pointer to structure while the pointer doesn't point to meaningful place. In other words you didn't allocate space to hold the structure object itself.

```
// allocate five objects
struct Yset *svg_ysets = malloc (5 * sizeof(struct Yset));
```

Don't forget to `free` if you are using dynamically allocated memory somewhere.

Comment: i know but i cant initialize an array with like this   struct Yset [] svg_ysets

Comment: @Berkin check the example in the answer.